# How to find out precisely what triggered the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using some function with jQuery, for example:

```
$(window).one('beforeunload', function() {
//my code
});
```

But I really want to find out all about what has triggered this event and how.

I tried the following code:

```
$(window).one('beforeunload', function(e) {
alert(JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

But it raises exception about circular structure. Definitely though there must be some other way of differentiating and debugging through it.

How am I going to apply it?

I want to see what triggered this event, was it a link, a submitted form, a javascript, a page refresh, or a back and forth buttons or whatever, and it's all fine in that case. **BUT** if it was triggered by a call to open an external application, I want to discard the event and return null.

Example of external application launch:

```
<a href="skype:your_skype_name?call" >
```

Any ideas?

**SOLVED**

This is how I solved it.

I just make some script link first, to gain more control over the event:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="skype_click_ok"
```

Then I create a global variable to store the state of beforeunload:

```
var dontunload=0;
```

Then I manually process the link, but setting location.href, and changing variable state:

```
$('#skype_click_ok').click(function(){
dontunload=1;
location.href='skype:marilynbrusas?call';
});
```

Now my actual beforeunload event, note the `one()` was also changed to `bind()`:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  if (dontunload==1) dontunload=0;  //if triggered from our skype - do nothing, yet  cancel state for the next call
  else {  //Do the actual code
          // Fade out, before leaving the page.
      $('html#my_html').stop(true,false).css('overflow','hidden').animate({opacity:0},2000);
      // Lock content with invalid image hack
          $('body#my_body').prepend(
        $('<div>').attr({style:'position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;left:0;top:0;z-index:900100;background-image:url(in-your-face)'})
      );
          // unbind the event
      $(this).unbind('beforeunload');
  }
});
```

**EDIT3**

Actually it's not solved. This trick does not work in IE and also the even triggers from javascript:void(0) links...

Comment: A call to open an external application ? Please, could you explain better ?

Comment: `<a href="skype:your_skype_name?call" >` - this does trigger a GET, and thus does trigger before-unload event. The external application means it has an internal protocol, other than `http:`, for example `skype:`. So it tries to launch a skype application instead of opening some page on the web. And I do want to cancel my event if it is the case.

Comment: Can you please post that "solved" section as an answer and remove it from your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `alert` to display objects like events is fairly useless.

Why don't you try sending you event to the **console**?

```
function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

This way you can expand you **event object** and view it in a a tree like structure.

**EDIT** As per you comments about the location of the event trigger: I haven't testing this, but this could be a way of stopping your unload event.

- Listen for click events for all `a` elements
- Check the element clicked points to an external application (doesn't start with http://)
- If not, bind an event handler for `beforeunload` that cancels the event immediately
- Otherwise unbind the previous handler

  ```
  $("a").click(function(event) {
    if(event.target.href.indexOf("http://") != 0) {
      $(window).on("beforeunload.override", function(e) {
        // Stop the 'beforeunload' event.
        return false;
      }
    }
    else {
      $(window).off("beforeunload.override");
    }
  }
  ```

Notice that this example is using something call **Event Namespacing**. By specifying that we want to listen to the `beforeunload` event, but we have our own namespace called `override`, we can add and remove the event handler safely without removing all other listeners for the `beforeunload` event.

Comment: Hell, that's exactly what I wanted, a list of properties, not just ID or tag name. Now I need only to find out a good way to catch that external application call.

Comment: Yeah I'm still not 100% sure on what you mean, but I've made some edits that might help.

Comment: Well it is tricky. The problem is that a href does not directly trigger the beforeunload event. Instead I do get 'HTMLDocument' as a event.target... A good thing is that you do understand what I'm trying to achieve now.

Comment: Well, that's a problem. The event will always have information on **precisely what triggered the event**. If it was triggered by **HTMLDocument**, then that's what it was triggered by. There is no magic way to backtrack through code to find out what happened before. You might have to start listening for multiple events, `$("a").click()` perhaps?.

Comment: That's what I've been thinking of, to asign some id for my link, replace the href to `javascript:void(0)` and then... and then I don't know... I would still have no idea what triggered the event. 

I could make a global variable of course, and set it up once the click to a skype link is observed. However I can't think of a way of reverting the state of that variable, so if the user yet again triggers the beforeunload event, but in an other way, it would yet again work as expected... hmmm, maybe I should revert it's state each time the before unload is called before the click, that's great idea

Comment: But It never works for some reason... let me update my question.

Comment: I made another edit. Maybe you could try playing around with it now.

Comment: That's cool man, glad to hear it. I was under the assumption that bind() had been deprecated for on()?

Comment: Yeah, I heard about it too recently. But I still don't get why shouldn't I use `bind()`? (a Jquery 1.64 user here...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `event.target.id` selector to pass what element triggered the event, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTY67/2/).
As the commentor mentioned, this will alert the ID of the element used to select, I just used that as an example as you didn't fully state what you wanted retrieved?

Comment: Well that will get the target id - if you remove the id portion it will get the element that triggered the event +1 though

Comment: I know how to get the element using event.target. But I rather want to log all of the properties of the event, I want to do debug it, it's not just enough going through this simplistic approach sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Using `target="_blank"` solves this problem as well:

```
<a href="skype:your_skype_name?call" target="_blank">
```

It's rather ugly, but in my case it was the only solution that flawlessly worked across all browsers.